# MongoDB Aggregate - Remove parent from response

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, aggregate, lookup

I am working with Node.JS and MongoDB. I got this working code :

```
 Thing.aggregate([
  { "$match": {  id_user: req.params.id} },
  {$set: {id_event: {$toObjectId: "$id_event"} }}, 
  {"$lookup": {
          "from": "events",
          "localField": "id_event",
          "foreignField": "_id",
          "as": "eventses"
      },
      
  }, 
  
  {"$project": {
    "_id" : 0,
    "eventses._id": 1,
    "eventses.title": 1,
    "eventses.description": 1,
    "eventses.creatorID": 1,
    "eventses.imageUrl": 1,
    "eventses.status": 1
  }
}
  
  ])
```

When I make a request, I get this response :

```
[
{
    "eventses": {
        "_id": "6109a94b6ac825000482a29f",
        "title": "Guidaille Crasino",
        "description": "6109a94b6ac825000482a29f",
        "creatorID": "UID123456",
        "imageUrl": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/77/Google_Images_2015_logo.svg/1200px-Google_Images_2015_logo.svg.png",
        "status": true
    }
},
{
    "eventses": {
        "_id": "6109a96c6ac825000482a2a1",
        "title": "Guidaille Néos",
        "description": "HEY",
        "creatorID": "UID123456",
        "imageUrl": "https://pic.clubic.com/v1/images/1862615/raw?fit=max&width=1200&hash=3b0c35819f6e4f879bd826ad6a85a87428ad512d",
        "status": true
    }
}
]
```

I am almost there but I would like to remove the "eventses" from the response and get this response instead :

```
[
{
    
        "_id": "6109a94b6ac825000482a29f",
        "title": "Guidaille Crasino",
        "description": "6109a94b6ac825000482a29f",
        "creatorID": "UID123456",
        "imageUrl": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/77/Google_Images_2015_logo.svg/1200px-Google_Images_2015_logo.svg.png",
        "status": true
   
},
{
   
        "_id": "6109a96c6ac825000482a2a1",
        "title": "Guidaille Néos",
        "description": "HEY",
        "creatorID": "UID123456",
        "imageUrl": "https://pic.clubic.com/v1/images/1862615/raw?fit=max&width=1200&hash=3b0c35819f6e4f879bd826ad6a85a87428ad512d",
        "status": true
    
}
]
```

I can't find a way to do it simply. Any idea how I could do that?

Thank you !

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/

Answer (score 0):

```
    Thing.aggregate([
      { "$match": {  id_user: req.params.id} },
      {$set: {id_event: {$toObjectId: "$id_event"} }}, // keep the whole document structure, but replace `id_event` into ObjectId      
      {"$lookup": {
              "from": "events",
              "localField": "id_event",
              "foreignField": "_id",
              "as": "eventses"
          },
          
      }, 
      {"$project": {
        "_id" : 0,
        "eventses._id": 1,
        "eventses.title": 1,
        "eventses.description": 1,
        "eventses.creatorID": 1,
        "eventses.imageUrl": 1,
        "eventses.status": 1
      }
    },
    { $unwind: "$eventses" },
    {
    $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$eventses" }} 
  ]).then(thing => res.status(200).json(thing))
```